# Why wouldn't windows load the WCID driver?

Tags: usb, usb-device, bootloader, windows

I'm developing an embedded device with a DFU compatible bootloader. Right now I can hold a button and enter the bootloader and download new binaries, but I thought I would make it more convenient for the user by employing the runtime features of the DFU spec.

My application configuration descriptor includes one extra interface(no endpoints) for the DFU Runtime, which responds to only one request `DFU_DETACH` by rebooting into the bootloader. This also works fine with non-windows platforms. On windows however, I need to make sure the WINUSB driver is loaded for this interface for this to work.

My Microsoft Compatible ID descriptor is setup as following.

```
USB_MicrosoftCompatibleDescriptor msft_compID = 
{
    .dwLength =  sizeof(USB_MicrosoftCompatibleDescriptor) + (2 * sizeof(USB_MicrosoftCompatibleDescriptor_Interface)),

    .bcdVersion = 0x0100,
    .wIndex = 0x0004,
    .bCount = 2,
    .interfaces = {
      {
        .bFirstInterfaceNumber = 0, //CDC
        .compatibleID = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        .subCompatibleID = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
      },
      {
        .bFirstInterfaceNumber = INTERFACE_DFU,
        .compatibleID = {0x57, 0x49, 0x4E, 0x55, 0x53, 0x42, 0x00, 0x00},
        .subCompatibleID = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
      }
    }
};
```

Windows recognizes this as a WINUSB device as shown in the attached image, but for some reason libusb is loaded instead of winusb, and I have to change the driver through Zadig inorder to get the DFU runtime interface to work.

[image: Compatible ID correctly displayed in device manager property page]
[image: Zadig screenshot showing wrong driver]

Specific question I'm asking here is, is there something else I should do to make sure windows loads the correct driver(WinUSB) without user intervention?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a valid EE question.

Comment: Superuser (since this is a windows usage problem) might be a more appropriate place.